# cfwheels, getting errors from an unsuccessful model update

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I'm trying to update a model with nested properties after an edit.

The update fails, but I'm not getting any errors using `#errorMessagesFor(objectName='myobject')#`.

Any idea how to get to the cause?

Comment: I usually debug wheels issues by diving into the core, and start sprinkling in `writeDump(var=loc, abort=true);` as needed until I can track down the issue.

Comment: What kind of association is the nested property set on? `belongsTo`, `hasMany`, or `hasOne`?

Comment: it's a **hasMany** association

Comment: The model has an array of objects, some of which do not exist in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the `allErrors()` method on each of the objects in the array.

```
for (local.object in myObject.arrayOfObjects) {
    if (local.object.hasErrors()) {
        WriteDump(var=local.object.allErrors(), abort=true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the Wheels google group and include some code examples.

If after the error happens in the controller if you do a redirect, the model object with the error doesn't exist, you'll have to do a renderpager.